# Ubuntu Terminal - gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--showme:link’

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am not trying to install anything. But the error message

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--showme:link’
```

pops up as the first line in my terminal whenever I launch it.

The problem existed in 14.04 and still exists after upgrading to 16.04.

Any idea why this happens and possible solutions?

The output of `cat ~/.bashrc` reads

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
source /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc
```

The output of `cat /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc` is

```
#----------------------------------*-sh-*--------------------------------------
# =========                 |
# \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
#  \\    /   O peration     |
#   \\  /    A nd           | Copyright (C) 2011-2015 OpenFOAM Foundation
#    \\/     M anipulation  |
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# License
#     This file is part of OpenFOAM.
#
#     OpenFOAM is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#     under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#     (at your option) any later version.
#
#     OpenFOAM is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
#     ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
#     for more details.
#
#     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#     along with OpenFOAM.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# File
#     etc/bashrc
#
# Description
#     Startup file for OpenFOAM
#     Sourced from ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc
#     Should be usable by any POSIX-compliant shell (eg, ksh)
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export WM_PROJECT=OpenFOAM
export WM_PROJECT_VERSION=3.0.1

################################################################################
# USER EDITABLE PART: Changes made here may be lost with the next upgrade
#
# either set $FOAM_INST_DIR before sourcing this file or set
# 'foamInstall' below to where OpenFOAM is installed
#
# Location of the OpenFOAM installation
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foamInstall=/opt
# foamInstall=~$WM_PROJECT
# foamInstall=/opt/$WM_PROJECT
# foamInstall=/usr/local/$WM_PROJECT
#
# END OF (NORMAL) USER EDITABLE PART
################################################################################

#
# These are the defaults for this version which should generally be
# overridden from the prefs.sh file or from command-line specification
#
#- note the location for later use (eg, in job scripts)
: ${FOAM_INST_DIR:=$foamInstall}; export FOAM_INST_DIR

#- Compiler location:
#    foamCompiler= system | ThirdParty (OpenFOAM)
foamCompiler=system

#- Compiler:
#    WM_COMPILER = Gcc | Gcc45 | Gcc46 | Gcc47 | Gcc48 | Gcc49| Clang | Icc
export WM_COMPILER=Gcc
unset WM_COMPILER_ARCH WM_COMPILER_LIB_ARCH

#- Memory addressing:
#    On a 64bit OS this can be 32bit or 64bit
#    On a 32bit OS addressing is 32bit and this option is not used
#    WM_ARCH_OPTION = 32 | 64
export WM_ARCH_OPTION=64

#- Precision:
#    WM_PRECISION_OPTION = DP | SP
export WM_PRECISION_OPTION=DP

#- Label size:
#    WM_LABEL_SIZE = 32 | 64
export WM_LABEL_SIZE=32

#- Optimised, debug, profiling:
#    WM_COMPILE_OPTION = Opt | Debug | Prof
export WM_COMPILE_OPTION=Opt

#- MPI implementation:
#    WM_MPLIB = SYSTEMOPENMPI | OPENMPI | SYSTEMMPI | MPICH | MPICH-GM | HPMPI
#               | MPI | QSMPI | SGIMPI
export WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI

#- Operating System:
#    WM_OSTYPE = POSIX | ???
export WM_OSTYPE=POSIX

#- Floating-point signal handling:
#    set or unset
export FOAM_SIGFPE=

#- memory initialisation:
#    set or unset
#export FOAM_SETNAN=


################################################################################

# The old dirs to be cleaned from the various environment variables
# - remove anything under top-level directory.
# NB: the WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR might not be identical between versions
foamOldDirs="$FOAM_INST_DIR $WM_PROJECT_SITE $HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER"
if [ "$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR" != "$FOAM_INST_DIR" ]
then
    foamOldDirs="$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR $foamOldDirs"
fi


# Location of installation
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR=$FOAM_INST_DIR
export WM_PROJECT_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/openfoam30

# Location of third-party software
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/ThirdParty-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION

# Location of site-specific templates etc
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# unset is equivalent to $WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/site
if [ -d "$WM_PROJECT_SITE" ]
then
    export WM_PROJECT_SITE
else
    unset WM_PROJECT_SITE
fi

# Location of user files
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR=$HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION


# Source files, possibly with some verbosity
_foamSource()
{
    while [ $# -ge 1 ]
    do
        [ "$FOAM_VERBOSE" -a "$PS1" ] && echo "Sourcing: $1" 1>&2
        . $1
       shift
    done
}

# Evaluate command-line parameters
_foamEval()
{
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        case "$1" in
        -*)
            # stray option (not meant for us here) -> get out
            break
            ;;
        *=)
            # name=       -> unset name
            [ "$FOAM_VERBOSE" -a "$PS1" ] && echo "unset ${1%=}" 1>&2
            eval "unset ${1%=}"
            ;;
        *=*)
            # name=value  -> export name=value
            [ "$FOAM_VERBOSE" -a "$PS1" ] && echo "export $1" 1>&2
            eval "export $1"
            ;;
        *)
            # filename: source it
            if [ -f "$1" ]
            then
                _foamSource "$1"
            else
                _foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile -silent "$1"`
            fi
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}


# Add in preset user or site preferences:
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile prefs.sh`

# Evaluate command-line parameters and record settings for later
# these can be used to set/unset values, or specify alternative pref files
export FOAM_SETTINGS="$@"
_foamEval $@

# Clean standard environment variables (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, MANPATH)
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foamClean=$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamCleanPath

#- Clean PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` \
    && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean MANPATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && MANPATH="$cleaned"

export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH


# Source project setup files
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config/settings.sh
_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config/aliases.sh


# Source user setup files for optional packages
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config/paraview.sh`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config/ensight.sh`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config/gperftools.sh`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config/CGAL.sh`


# Clean environment paths again. Only remove duplicates
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#- Clean PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH"` && PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean MANPATH (trailing ':' to find system pages)
cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH"`: && MANPATH="$cleaned"

export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH

#- Clean LD_PRELOAD
if [ -n "$LD_PRELOAD" ]
then
    cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_PRELOAD"` && LD_PRELOAD="$cleaned"
    export LD_PRELOAD
fi


# cleanup environment:
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
unset cleaned foamClean foamInstall foamOldDirs
unset _foamSource _foamEval

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- end-of-file
```

Comment: Whats the output of `grep -Hn 'gcc' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile`?

Comment: What? What command did you run?

Comment: @heemayl  Sorry my bad! There is no output.

Comment: Ok. Now do `grep -Hn 'showme:link' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile`

Comment: @heemayl No output again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc`

Comment: And whats the output of `cat /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc`? Also is your formatting right at the end of your input? The `if-else` part is broken.

Comment: Does commenting out `source /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc` solve it?

Comment: @heemayl: That worked. Thanks a lot. If you write that as the answer, I will mark it as solution. And can you explain what you did there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `~/.bashrc` has the following line at the end:

```
source /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc
```

i.e. `bash` will source `/opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc` while starting an interactive session.

And in that file you have the potential problem as other portions seem fairly normal. But the interesting thing is that file does not directly call `gcc` but it `source`s so many other files, it really hard to get to the specific file/line that is causing this issue.

Instead, as an trial and error method (and also being confident that this should be the problematic one), you can comment out the line from `~/.bashrc`:

```
# source /opt/openfoam30/etc/bashrc
```

And as per your comment, it worked !! The error message is gone.

---

For future, the first step to debug these sort of `bash` session starting related issue, check if the relevant files have anything:

For Login Interactive session of `bash`:

```
grep -Hn 'gcc' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile
```

For Non-login Interactive session of `bash`:

```
grep -Hn 'gcc' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
```

If not, read the relevant files, you should get a hint to debug further.